# How can I create a global CSS file for my react project to apply to all components?

Tags: reactjs

I am still new to React, so any help is greatly appreciated!

I am trying to create one css file "Global.css" that only needs to be imported at the top of my React project (Index.js or App.js) and will apply to all of my child components. Is this possible to do?

A normal import for me looks like this:

`import "/css/Global.css"`

So I am not using the modules "App.module.css" or anything like that.

I have tried importing it into App.js and using `require("/css/Global.css")` in App.js, but neither worked.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you tried to load your css file in index.js?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. React boilerplate projects usually include a file for the entire app [out of the box](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/global-styles.js). Please revise your question to ask about your _specific_ case. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: you need to use es5 syntax import in react, also you can add a global css in in the public/index.html, like  this <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/components/icon.min.css">